# How to embed hash in exe file with signtool.exe

Tags: hash, certificate, digital-signature, signtool

I am using signtool.exe to sign exe file.
I am trying to embed my exe file with the .pfx certificate along with the signed hash of exe(generated signed hash using openssl). I am able to sign only with certificate. But I need to embed the signed hash in the exe as well. Probably  **signtool.exe sign /as** could help. **/as** option does not expect any argument so not able to pass my hash there.

Could someone please help me sign my exe with certificate and hash.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The version of Signtool shipped with the Windows 10 SDK includes the capability to embed a signed hash into an exe.

From the following page:
https://vcsjones.com/2017/05/07/custom-authenticode-signing/

> Starting in the Windows 10 SDK, two new command line switches are available, `dg` and `di`. Recall that a signature is always performed on a hash on Authenticode. The `dg` option changes signtool’s behavior to output a digest that you can sign using anything you’d like. Let’s try this on a copy of notepad.exe.

```
signtool sign /dg "C:\scratch\dir" /fd SHA256 /f public-cert.cer notepad.exe
```

> This takes a file to a public certificate - there is no key in
>   public-cert.cer. You could also use the `/sha1` option to specify a
>   certificate in the certificate store that also has only a public key.
>   This will output a few files in the “C:\scratch\dir” directory. The
>   digest is the one with the “.dig” extension. This file will have the
>   Base64 encoded digest to sign. Next, using your custom tool, sign the
>   digest with the private key for the certificate. You should decode the
>   Base64 signature before signing if the signing API expects a raw
>   binary digest.
>
> Next, encode your signature in base64 and place it in a file in the
>   “C:\scratch\dir” directory with the same name as the digest file, with
>   the “signed” extension. For example, “notepad.exe.dig.signed”.
>
> The next step is to ingest the signed digest along with the rest of
>   the Authenticode signature to complete the signing.

```
signtool sign /di "C:\scratch\dir" notepad.exe
```

> This will complete the signing process, and we now have our own signed
>   copy of notepad.exe. Appending a signature is done just as before,
>   except with the `/as` flag.
>
> This provides great flexibility for signers to use non CSP / CNG
>   signing options, or offloading the signing process. Signtool can now
>   also sign just a plain digest file using the `/ds` option. If you have a
>   dedicated server for performing Authenticode signing, you can now use
>   the `/dg`, `/ds`, `/di` options so that only a very small file needs to be
>   moved to the signing server, instead of the entirely binary if they
>   are large in size.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work:

SignTool Error: The /dg /ds /di option is incompatible with the /seal /itos /as option.

Comment: The /as flag is only needed when appending an additional signature. If there is only one signature then just using the /di flag should work. If you get an error that no signature is present, your signed digest is probably wrong.