# Signing EXE using signed hash

Tags: windows, security, certificate, code-signing, signing

For signing windows applications/installers it is recommended to use 'signtool'. My concern is that my signing certificate isn't there on same machine where signing will happen. I can generate hash of the application and send it to another machine containing the certificate. That machine will sign the hash and send it back to me. Now I would require mechanism to sign the windows application using just the signed hash.

Comment: Looks like there is answer available to it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645842/how-to-embed-hash-in-exe-file-with-signtool-exe